# Is there a codelab that teaches how to use Web Components in Dart?

Tags: dart, web-component

I heard there's a codelab that teaches you how to use Web Components in Dart? Is that true? If so, what do I do if I get stuck?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! It's true! I know because I was the one who wrote it!

Here's the PDF for the codelab: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui-code-lab/blob/master/dart_web_ui_codelab.pdf?raw=true

Here's the source code for the codelab: https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui-code-lab

If you have any problems, just post your questions to Stack Overflow with the "dart" tag!

Happy Hacking!